# Difference between server clean and project clean

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse there are two options to available to clean. Whats the difference between them, i.e, Project -> Clean and Servers -> Clean ?

Answer (score 4):

The first option removes the build results of a project - generated classes, binaries etc. The second option removes the current deployments form a server.

Comment: So you mean when I use project -> clean, it won't make changes to my current deployments in server ?

Comment: Probably not, since eclipse uses the source folders for deployment per default. It can have an impact however, if you have defined the deployment to use your `target` or `bin` folders. You can verify that in your server settings inside eclipse.